# Zend framework 2 load php file with constants

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a file called `Message.php` in `module/Cms/language` directory. This file contain constants like below

```
<?php
define("APPLICATION_TITLE","Test Application");
?>
```

When module is running I would like to use such constant anywhere in the module scope. I understand I can load this by modifying `config_glob_paths` in `application.config.php`

But I am looking for a way where this file will be loaded only for the module specified. Can I have some configuration in `module.config.php` for this. Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define the contants when the module `CMS` loads use the `Module::onBootstrap()` method.

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(Event $e)
    {
       include_once( __DIR__  . '/language/English.php');
    }
}
```

More information about the bootstrap event is [documented here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-class.html#the-mvc-bootstrap-event).

Optionally the Module class can implement the `Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\OnBootstrapListener`. Which is [documented here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-manager.html).